Hard Link is breaking with npm install
We had same code for windows and mac users and we use electron. So we create a separate package-win.json, package-lock-win.json for windows and package-mac.json, package-lock-mac.json for mac. Now whenever our developers were running any scripts which were our own customer script, we had done the following:
    if [ "$m" == "installDependencies" ]; then
        nvm use v14.16.0 32
        if [ -f "package.json" ]; then
            rm package.json
        fi
        if [ -f "package-lock.json" ]; then
            rm package-lock.json
        fi
        ln package-win.json package.json
        ln package-lock-win.json package-lock.json
        npm install
    fi

What this does is basically creates a package.json and package-lock.json according to OS depending package files and developers can work using them.
Now the problem that is happening is after npm install, the hard link is being broken. If I don't do npm install in the script command and if I am changing in package.json, it is getting copy pasted to package-win.json and vice-versa due to hard link. Same happens with package-lock files. But somehow due to npm install, the hard link does not work and after npm install, if I do any change, it is not being copy pasted.
Any Solution for this? I have tried npm link ( not applicable in our case ), symbolic links ( cannot use since we want to carry the changes between files. ) and I don't want to use the post-install scripts.
I was expecting that the hard link will remain there between the two files unless I delete either one of them ( target or original file ).
I have two questions:

Why does hard link breaks on npm install?
What's the best way to solve this problem?


"I was expecting that the hard link will remain there between the two files".  If ln foo bar succeeds, it does not create a file.  There are not two files.  There is one file, and it has (at least) 2 names.   Do not think of one of the names as "target" and the other as "original".  They are both equally valid names to the file.

Yeah, I was expecting the same. But the hard link does not remain after the npm install. Changes does not get copy pasted across the 2 names after npm install but they do if I omit npm install.

npm install rewrites package-lock.json.  This would conventionally take the form of writing a new file then renaming it to package-lock.json, which will indeed break the link.  And that's probably what you want, too, as opposed to modifying the file that is (also) accessible as package-lock-win.json.  I'm not sure about package.json, though.  Are you sure its link is being broken too?

Overall, hard links are kinda nasty.  They have a few legitimate uses, but a lot of baggage.  Use soft links instead where you can, and prefer something (anything) else entirely most other places.
